# Chain ADF pipe line with feeding output

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to chain 2 Azure Data Factory pipelines A -> B so that the pipeline B consumes the output of the Pipe line A.
So, basically A is a authorization pipeline that has few activities, the last of which produces the authentication token.  Now that token I want use in the Pipeline B (and C, and D.. etc...).  So, basically I want to reuse pipe line A.
I used Execute Pipleline activity but, its output is NOT what I expect .. How can use the actual output of A in B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out how to solve this, for my case at least.
Since, I am dealing with (in the particular case) with the authentication token, I made use of the Azure Key Vault.  Where, in the last activity of a pipe line A  I POST the acquired token to the Azure key vault as a named secret.
In the pipeline B - what I do is I call 'execute Pipeline' activity - executing pipe line A.  After that on completion, calling the web activity to read the token acquired in 'A'.  And as a next activity in "B" I am using that token in API.

Comment: Great,Also if you can configure a schedule trigger you can get rid of the execute pipeline inside pipeline A

Answer (score 1):

Create Pipeline B

Click on Parameters
Add a parameter value ->inputfromA and give Default value as blank
Create a variable fromA and in the value,click on add dynamic content->@pipeline().parameters.inputfromA

Create Pipeline A

Store the value of authorization token in some variable
Add a execute pipeline and on InvokedPipeline->add pipelineB
Then it will ask to input the value of inputfromA ->click add dynamic content and then you can add the token value there.

Comment: Thank you.  What you say works.
However, this is NOT what I was asking.  Basically what you say is ... that inside pipe line A, I should already KNOW that I will be calling pipe line B.  And this is not the goal I am after.  I can achieve this with just another activity inside pipe line A.
My goal was to have a 'pipe line A' and save it as a library !!.   
So, 'pipeLine A' logs the user in, and SAVES the authentication token, which has to be available to any other pipeline that can be run.  
Idealy, I want to share a variable with the token across pipelines.

Comment: @DmitriyRyabin I have one idea.You can save the token in any database table right?After that you can retrieve this token value from any other pipelines

Comment: Yes, it will work.  I can also save the whole authentication response as a JSON file on the Azure Blob storage space.  And reference it from Pipeline B.  Still, would have been interesting to know how to share variables between pipe lines.